# Understanding the result of modulo operator: %%

Tags: r, operators

I'm trying to understand how the `%%` operator works in R:

```
10 %% 10  # 0
20 %% 10  # 0
```

I'm not sure about these two results:

```
10 %% 20  # 10
2 %% 8  # 2
```

Can you help me understand the last two results? I'm a little confused.

Comment: While Zhenyuan Li gives a good answer, I think what you did was confuse the order of arguments.  If you had expected `10 %% 20` to return 0, you probably actually wanted to do `20 %% 10`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Remainder_calculation_for_the_modulo_operation

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Nothing wrong:

```
10 = 1 * 10 + 0
20 = 2 * 10 + 0
10 = 0 * 20 + 10
2  = 0 * 8  + 2
```

The modulo is the number after `+`.

---

In general, for two numbers `a` and `b`, there is

```
a = floor(a / b) * b + (a %% b)
```

Let's write a toy function:

```
foo <- function(a,b) c(quotient = floor(a / b), modulo = a %% b)

foo(10, 10)
#quotient   modulo 
#   1        0 

foo(20, 10)
#quotient   modulo 
#   2        0 

foo(10, 20)
#quotient   modulo 
#   0       10 

foo(2, 8)
#quotient   modulo 
#   0        2
```

---

**Update**: Instead of using `floor(a / b)` to get quotient, we can also use `a %/% b`.

Answer (score 8):

I'll offer another explanation. Take this problem:

```
20 %% 10 = 0
```

Instead of evaluating the modulo, start with simple divison:

```
20 / 10 = 2
```

As you know, the answer "2" means that it takes two sets of 10 to get 20. Note that we can also write the answer this way with the decimal, 2.0.

The decimal is important. When the decimal is .0, we have no remainder. We have complete sets. If division yields a 0 decimal, then the modulo evaluates to zero.

Now consider this:

```
11/3 = 3.667
```

That tail part, the 0.667, is the portion of a set of 3 that remains *after we form all full sets of 3 that we can*. On the left side of the decimal, we show:

```
#Splitting the answer into its components - 3 full sets, 0.667 partial sets
3.0 + 0.667 = 3.667
```

So if we want to know the actual remaining quantity, we can multiply 0.667 by the divisor, 3:

```
0.667 * 3 = 2
```

This is the remainder. It is the **quantity** that remains after all full sets of 3 are formed. It's the same result we get using modulo:

```
11 %% 3 = 2
```

The same applies here. Given this problem,

```
10 %% 20 = 10
```

we can divide normally and get:

```
10 / 20 = 0.5
```

Reading this out, we have 0 full groups of 20 (left side); we only have half a set, 0.5, of 20.

```
0.5 * 20 = 10
```

This is equivalent to:

```
10 %% 20 = 10
```

10 is thus the remainder. It's the gap between the 10 we have and the 10 we need to get to 20.

Answer (score 4):

I was also very confused, but if you understand that the result of the %% operator is the REMAINDER of a division, it is very easy.

Eg. `75%%4 = 3`

and I noticed if the *dividend* is lower than the *divisor*, then R returns the same *dividend* value.

Eg.

```
4%%75 = 4
10 %% 20  = 10
2 %% 8  = 2
```

[image: division parts]

Answer (score 1):

Trying to understand some results in R with x modulo y I found this page. Then trying to explain to myself some "quirky" results I wrote this R script below. I had read that the remainder or result of modulo operator is supposed to be always positive, but this is not the case in R, and the definition and example provide here explain the logic that seems to be used. Definition `x mod y = x - ( |_x/y_| * y)` where `|_x/y_| = floor(x/y)` seems to always be true in R, or in a more standard way, the definition of the remainder `r` of the operation `q = x / y is x = k*q + r`, where `k` and `r` both are integers.

Basically in R with `x = 2` and `y = - 5`, `x mod y = -3`; or using definition `x = k*q + r` we have `r = x - k*q = -3`.

Still, this is kind of quirky in a mathematical sense because "integer part product" (`k*q`) actually exceeds the dividend (`x`), thus defining the remainder (`r`) as a negative integer...

```
x <- 2    
y <- -5
q <- x/y
k <- floor(2/-5)
kq <- floor(2/-5) * -5
r <- 2 - (floor(2/-5) * -5)
x %% y
```

Answer (score 1):

## Syntax

```
remainder <- dividend %% divisor
```

## Details

The only thing that were missing from the [documentations](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/Arithmetic) were the details on which side is the **dividend** and which side is the **divisor**. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Introduction) describes the two terms as:

> What is being divided is called the dividend, which is divided by the divisor, and the result is called the quotient. In the example, 20 is the dividend, 5 is the divisor, and 4 is the quotient.

However, in comparison with the division operation, the modulo operation is not returning the **quotient**. Instead, it is returning the **remainder**.

### Examples

To easily understand the modulo operation, ideally the **dividend** > **divisor**.

```
12 %% 11
# quotient is 1.090909
# remainder is 1

12 %% 10
# quotient is 1.2
# remainder is 2

12 %% 9
# quotient is 1.333333
# remainder is 3

12 %% 8
# quotient is 1.5
# remainder is 4

12 %% 7
# quotient is 1.714286
# remainder is 5

12 %% 6
# quotient is 2
# remainder is 0
# 12 is divisible by 6

12 %% 5
# quotient is 2.4
# remainder is 2

12 %% 4
# quotient is 3
# remainder is 0
# 12 is divisible by 4

12 %% 3
# quotient is 4
# remainder is 0
# 12 is divisible by 3

12 %% 2
# quotient is 6
# remainder is 0
# 12 is divisible by 2

12 %% 1
# quotient is 12
# remainder is 0
# any whole number is divisible by 1
```